# CoreData Mapping Models Over Two Schema Versions Failing

Tags: ios, core-data

I'm trying to load data from a version two databases back. So I'm trying to load data from revision A, and I have a mapping model from A->B, and then B->C.

This isn't working. I'm not sure why. I can see from the logs it sees all the mapping models with the right UUIDs, it just won't make the jump to running the two mapping models. Logs attached.

```
    2013-11-06 16:49:14.751 DigimarcDiscover[4691:1603] CoreData: annotation: Incompatible version schema for persistent store 'file:///var/mobile/Applications/706DD1D2-E136-4028-9F3A-97C888CC1CD1/Library/Application%20Support/History.db'.  store metadata = {
    NSPersistenceFrameworkVersion = 481;
    NSStoreModelVersionHashes =     {
        BarcodeHistoryItem = <ad40b955 0fdcbf91 efd12f35 5ab2737a ad57635a 7b9bd32a a4aaecaf 6eb6ffb0>;
        HistoryItem = <8be6112c 2517affe 7496c522 c267a485 1b002285 057a735b d38e79c1 b2700406>;
        MusicHistoryItem = <180e1207 9c41a970 bcd190bb 33b1d55e f4f6fe93 99167a2c c5b9aadd add4281e>;
        WatermarkHistoryItem = <a55bab71 2e03c10f 6f59c567 64bd48c3 bed015c8 05ed9cbf a3253b44 02a9c783>;
    };
    NSStoreModelVersionHashesVersion = 3;
    NSStoreModelVersionIdentifiers =     (
        ""
    );
    NSStoreType = SQLite;
    NSStoreUUID = "B2C6A3EE-A000-4641-A2EC-8F30FFD66F92";
    "_NSAutoVacuumLevel" = 2;
} and current model versions = {
    Artwork = <952d1ac4 6e13d942 c50b66d3 87b0abac 48a443ac c39a5600 4c2dd9fb d3628c39>;
    BarcodeHistoryItem = <b0f8ac5f 1b88e0bd 02c58aa0 318c6528 d4a2d875 e1cb2a0e 0f7a97a3 cbabf8df>;
    HistoryItem = <816029f3 a3d5291f 118de2b3 0522e405 8dc8e24b 7bcc12e4 c76aaa4f 5ac819db>;
    MusicHistoryItem = <2845a594 da975d6f 01cb8c22 439446cd 88b3749c 3efbc146 cd081387 0fc7b151>;
    ThumbnailItem = <97e6c0c6 0eea0170 3870ca94 348d8ff8 437fc4ca ce8e11c1 1623ff07 5ea78ad4>;
    WatermarkHistoryItem = <c65a4768 ddae03fd 870a3136 0a3ccd77 000776b7 b14d4354 d4ac1126 65473d1a>;
}
2013-11-06 16:49:14.760 DigimarcDiscover[4691:1603] CoreData: annotation: (migration)    will attempt automatic schema migration
2013-11-06 16:49:15.072 DigimarcDiscover[4691:1603] CoreData: annotation: (migration) looking for mapping model with 
 source hashes: 
{
    BarcodeHistoryItem = <ad40b955 0fdcbf91 efd12f35 5ab2737a ad57635a 7b9bd32a a4aaecaf 6eb6ffb0>;
    HistoryItem = <8be6112c 2517affe 7496c522 c267a485 1b002285 057a735b d38e79c1 b2700406>;
    MusicHistoryItem = <180e1207 9c41a970 bcd190bb 33b1d55e f4f6fe93 99167a2c c5b9aadd add4281e>;
    WatermarkHistoryItem = <a55bab71 2e03c10f 6f59c567 64bd48c3 bed015c8 05ed9cbf a3253b44 02a9c783>;
}
 destination hashes: {
    Artwork = <952d1ac4 6e13d942 c50b66d3 87b0abac 48a443ac c39a5600 4c2dd9fb d3628c39>;
    BarcodeHistoryItem = <b0f8ac5f 1b88e0bd 02c58aa0 318c6528 d4a2d875 e1cb2a0e 0f7a97a3 cbabf8df>;
    HistoryItem = <816029f3 a3d5291f 118de2b3 0522e405 8dc8e24b 7bcc12e4 c76aaa4f 5ac819db>;
    MusicHistoryItem = <2845a594 da975d6f 01cb8c22 439446cd 88b3749c 3efbc146 cd081387 0fc7b151>;
    ThumbnailItem = <97e6c0c6 0eea0170 3870ca94 348d8ff8 437fc4ca ce8e11c1 1623ff07 5ea78ad4>;
    WatermarkHistoryItem = <c65a4768 ddae03fd 870a3136 0a3ccd77 000776b7 b14d4354 d4ac1126 65473d1a>;
}
2013-11-06 16:49:15.085 DigimarcDiscover[4691:1603] CoreData: annotation: (migration) checking mapping model /var/mobile/Applications/706DD1D2-E136-4028-9F3A-97C888CC1CD1/DigimarcDiscover.app/MappingModel.cdm
 source hashes: 
{(
    <8be6112c 2517affe 7496c522 c267a485 1b002285 057a735b d38e79c1 b2700406>,
    <ad40b955 0fdcbf91 efd12f35 5ab2737a ad57635a 7b9bd32a a4aaecaf 6eb6ffb0>,
    <a55bab71 2e03c10f 6f59c567 64bd48c3 bed015c8 05ed9cbf a3253b44 02a9c783>,
    <180e1207 9c41a970 bcd190bb 33b1d55e f4f6fe93 99167a2c c5b9aadd add4281e>
)}
 destination hashes: {(
    <952d1ac4 6e13d942 c50b66d3 87b0abac 48a443ac c39a5600 4c2dd9fb d3628c39>,
    <b0f8ac5f 1b88e0bd 02c58aa0 318c6528 d4a2d875 e1cb2a0e 0f7a97a3 cbabf8df>,
    <816029f3 a3d5291f 118de2b3 0522e405 8dc8e24b 7bcc12e4 c76aaa4f 5ac819db>,
    <2845a594 da975d6f 01cb8c22 439446cd 88b3749c 3efbc146 cd081387 0fc7b151>,
    <97e6c0c6 0eea0170 3870ca94 348d8ff8 437fc4ca ce8e11c1 1623ff07 5ea78ad4>,
    <cf2033c8 0fc04c69 6a905095 bb8d3f2e 20775b82 66cdf0bf b33cc93c ea42d214>
)}
2013-11-06 16:49:15.090 DigimarcDiscover[4691:1603] CoreData: annotation: (migration) mismatched  and destination hashes for mapping model MappingModel.cdm
2013-11-06 16:49:15.091 DigimarcDiscover[4691:1603] CoreData: annotation: (migration) no match found for 1 of 6 mapping model destination hashes
2013-11-06 16:49:15.103 DigimarcDiscover[4691:1603] CoreData: annotation: (migration) checking mapping model /var/mobile/Applications/706DD1D2-E136-4028-9F3A-97C888CC1CD1/DigimarcDiscover.app/MappingModel40to50.cdm
 source hashes: 
{(
    <952d1ac4 6e13d942 c50b66d3 87b0abac 48a443ac c39a5600 4c2dd9fb d3628c39>,
    <b0f8ac5f 1b88e0bd 02c58aa0 318c6528 d4a2d875 e1cb2a0e 0f7a97a3 cbabf8df>,
    <cf2033c8 0fc04c69 6a905095 bb8d3f2e 20775b82 66cdf0bf b33cc93c ea42d214>,
    <2845a594 da975d6f 01cb8c22 439446cd 88b3749c 3efbc146 cd081387 0fc7b151>,
    <97e6c0c6 0eea0170 3870ca94 348d8ff8 437fc4ca ce8e11c1 1623ff07 5ea78ad4>,
    <816029f3 a3d5291f 118de2b3 0522e405 8dc8e24b 7bcc12e4 c76aaa4f 5ac819db>
)}
 destination hashes: {(
    <952d1ac4 6e13d942 c50b66d3 87b0abac 48a443ac c39a5600 4c2dd9fb d3628c39>,
    <b0f8ac5f 1b88e0bd 02c58aa0 318c6528 d4a2d875 e1cb2a0e 0f7a97a3 cbabf8df>,
    <816029f3 a3d5291f 118de2b3 0522e405 8dc8e24b 7bcc12e4 c76aaa4f 5ac819db>,
    <c65a4768 ddae03fd 870a3136 0a3ccd77 000776b7 b14d4354 d4ac1126 65473d1a>,
    <2845a594 da975d6f 01cb8c22 439446cd 88b3749c 3efbc146 cd081387 0fc7b151>,
    <97e6c0c6 0eea0170 3870ca94 348d8ff8 437fc4ca ce8e11c1 1623ff07 5ea78ad4>
)}
2013-11-06 16:49:15.105 DigimarcDiscover[4691:1603] CoreData: annotation: (migration) mismatched source and  hashes for mapping model MappingModel40to50.cdm
2013-11-06 16:49:15.109 DigimarcDiscover[4691:1603] CoreData: annotation: (migration) no suitable mapping model found
```

Comment: Could you show your loading code? Also, please describe you scenario - maybe there is a different solution.

Comment: Are you doing a migration? Try search `progressivelyMigrateURL:` and check out [Custom Core Data migrations](http://www.objc.io/issue-4/core-data-migration.html)

Comment: Puttin: You're on the right track! But now I hit a new problem. The progressive migration renames the database files, and I use attributes with external storage. This means the external storage files get separated from their database! Is there a non-hacky way to move a CoreData database along with it's external storage?

Comment: Ok, figured it out. I just create a store co-ordinator to do the migration in place instead of using the migration classes in Puttin's example, but similar sort of recursive migration. Puttin, if you submit this as an answer, I'll gladly give you the points for it!